# PHP upper case equal lower case

Tags: php, operator-keyword

How can I **ignore upper case and lowercase** and say that:

> $operator = /* Is equal to */
>
> 'apple' $operator 'APPLE'

or any Idea how to get same result with other way? *( except using strtolower() )*

Comment: [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)  Is this what you are looking for?! (Quick google search; SO != Google)

Comment: @MarkBaker You were too fast: *except using strtolower()*

Comment: You could use `strtoupper()` instead ?. (:grin:)

Comment: @Rizier123 not only Markbaker but also you.Every time I see a new question most the time I see both of you commented already. I was going to write the same comment as Mark did but while typing I see new comment and it was already posted.

Comment: @spencer7593 You mean: `$str = implode("", array_map(function($v){return chr(ord($v)+32);}, str_split($str)));` :)?

Comment: btw why so restriction using strtolower?

Comment: @GiorgiKhmaladze So ^ is strcasecmp() now what you are looking for? Or do you want to write your own function??

Comment: Or, as long as regular expression "special" characters are escaped, we could use `eregi` function (do do case insensitive regular expression pattern matching).  :)

Comment: @Rizier123 ty it helped, I was testing it... I was just testing if it changed all characters in upper or lower...

Comment: @GiorgiKhmaladze So question answered or are you looking for something different?

Comment: @Rizier123 nope, it has been answered

Comment: @GiorgiKhmaladze please add an aswer, if you found it

Comment: @beppe9000 i have just read ur comment, and i posted answer, u can see if u like

Comment: @GiorgiKhmaladze good, you improved this page's quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is function in PHP called [strcasecmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php). This is used for case-insensitive string comparison.